# Is there a way to make the a glossary entry clickable?

Tags: latex, glossaries

I'm making a glossary using the package `\usepackage{glossaries}`. This works fine but I have a slight problem.

I would like to make the word I call from the glossary (with `\gls(a_word)`) clickable, so the reader is automatically taken to the glossary entry that match the word he clicked on.

So far, I tried to use hyperlinks, without any success, and I couldn't find a similar problem on Internet nor on SO.

I hope you will be able to help me out with this!

Thanks by advance

Edit: Here's the code I'm using

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,toc,chapter=chapter]{glossaries}
```

In glossary:

```
\makeglossaries

\setglossarypreamble{Source is INSEE}

\newglossaryentry{AAV}
{
    name=AAV,
    description={The description of what AAV is.}
}
```

[image: The output in Glossary]

In document:

```
sometextsometext (see \Gls{AAV}). Sometextsometext
```

[image: The text in the document]

Comment: Please make a [mre]. You probably want to have a look at the hyperref package

Comment: Edited @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load the `hyperref` package, the abbreviation will automatically be clickable:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setglossarypreamble{Source is INSEE}

\newglossaryentry{AAV}
{
    name=AAV,
    description={The description of what AAV is.}
}


\begin{document}

sometextsometext (see \Gls{AAV}). Sometextsometext

\printglossaries


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The issue was that the package `\usepackage{hyperref}` was loaded after `\usepackage{glossaries}`

Comment: @MonJeanJean That's why a question should have a compilable [mre] and not just code fragments